# Texture shows up correctly in edit mode, but not in object mode (Object is ABC import)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I am working on a motion capture scene, exported from Motionbuilder so I had to import it as an ABC sequence in Blender, as Blender imports a broken mess when I try to load the FBX of my mocap.

Anyways, ABC is great but it completely erases my UVs, at least when I export it from Maya, so I need to re-import my models with correct UVs, and copy it onto the ABC.

Problem is, with one of my character, his pants texture and chest texture are just one singular color in object mode, but they appear completely fine in edit mode

[image: Character in object mode, reference of what the chest and pants are supposed to look like in background]

[image: In edit mode, Object is completely fine and for some reason the head re-appears ??]

UVs in the UV editor look completely fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks !!

Comment: As an alternative solution, I exported my scene in USD with Animation Data checked in maya, which bakes the animation in the same way ABC does but this time it copies the UVs and the problem is no more. Still curious as to why this is happening  though